# How to kill os.chdir() and use the further code

Tags: python

Here is my script would do

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.environ['TEMP'], 'HOME'))
>>> TEMPHOME = os.path.join(os.environ['TEMP'], 'HOME')
>>> TEMPHOME
'C:\\Users\\PURUSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\HOME'
>>> os.chdir(TEMPHOME)
```

after trying the same directory using the os.rmdir() throws error as below, how can get it working?

```
>>> os.rmdir(TEMPHOME)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    os.rmdir(TEMPHOME)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\PURUSH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\HOME'
```

Comment: You need to not have it as the current working directory. `chdir` to somewhere else.

Comment: It ain't the `os.chdir()` that is using that directory, is your application after call that command, your current app (python shell) is using that directory, ergo, you can delete it.

Comment: The error message is clear: another process (for instance Explorer) is locking your folder.

Comment: no actually i have to change the directory and finish commands execution and come back to deletion.. intended to do that..

Comment: if you're changing directory to execute a command using `subprocess`, there's a `cwd` flag which will save you the hassle of `chdir`. Using `os.chdir()` is bad practice.

Comment: `orig_path = os.getcwd()` ... do your work ... `os.chdir(orig_path)`. Now you can delete it.... if its empty. Otherwise consider `shutil.rmtree`.

Comment: can you explain in code?

Comment: thank you all, it works now by the way of @tdelaney

Answer (score 3):

Just remember your original directory and restore when done.

```
import os
TEMPHOME = os.path.join(os.environ['TEMP'], 'HOME')
orig_dir = os.getcwd()
try:
    os.chdir(TEMPHOME)
    .... do your work
finally:
    os.chdir(orig_dir)
```

You could leverage existing temporary directory code by building your own context manager on top of TemporaryDirectory

```
import os
import tempfile

class TempChdir(tempfile.TemporaryDirectory):

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()
        self.orig_dir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.name)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        os.chdir(self.orig_dir)
        super().__exit__(*args)


with TempChdir() as tmpdir:
    ... do your work
```

Not sure that was easier but looks fancier.